# How to get Args from Provider (c# .NET Core console app)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, singleton, console-application

I try to make a .NET Core console app with singleton. In main I have:

```
Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

        var services = ConfigureServices();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        serviceProvider.GetService<App>().Run();
```

and in App.cs:

```
public App(IConfiguration config, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        conf = config;

        var list = configuration.Providers.ToList();
        var provider = (CommandLineConfigurationProvider)list[1];

    }
```

How can I download `string[]` (or list, or whatever) with arguments from provider?

Comment: You can use `Environment.GetCommanLineArgs()` to get the raw command line to the application. The providers are an abstraction, so don't give you access to exactly what was passed into them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer provided by [Martin Costello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064169/martin-costello) (from comments):

> You can use [`Environment.GetCommanLineArgs()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=netcore-3.1) to get the raw command line to the application. The providers are an abstraction, so don't give you access to exactly what was passed into them.
>
> Link: [learn.microsoft.com: GetCommandLineArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=netcore-3.1)